# datatable empty after receiving data

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable, primeng

I'm using primeng datatable to preview data .

I'm using a service to get data from json.

```
this.searchUserService.getResultART().then(data => {
  console.log(data); // data is OK
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    this.usersList.push(new User(data[i]));
  }
  console.log("user list ", this.usersList); // list OK
});
```

In HTML I create my datatable

```
<p-dataTable [value]="usersList" selectionMode="single"  [(selection)]="selectedUser" dataKey="uid" (onRowSelect)="selectedUserDetails($event)" styleClass="tab-result"  >
  <p-column field="uid" header="UID" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
  <p-column field="firstName" header="First Name" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
  <p-column field="lastName" header="Last Name" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
  <p-column field="buildingAdress" header="Address" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
  <p-column field="profile" header="Role" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

What I have in screen is empty table with no records message.

Console.log shows me right data, I dont know why table is still empty

Comment: Do all the field names match exactly whats being returned by JSON?

Comment: Yes exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

I see this happen a lot where the component doesn't realize the input has changed because, well it hasn't, only the properties of the input have.

In your callback, try creating a new array by calling `Array.concat()` on the existing array with the newly mapped results from data.  This should trigger the change detection in the component, because now the reference being passed into the input has changed.

```
this.searchUserService.getResultART().then(data =>
  this.usersList = this.usersList.concat(data.map(x => new User(x)));
);
```